# DBF file insertion in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I need to insert different data into a **DBF file**.

I have a DBF file already created (a kind of template) with the different columns but without any data.

My program makes a copy of this file and inserts the recovered data from a CSV file, I give the correct formats to each of the data before inserting it and it works fine.

However, my program may have to perform this operation again if it finds other CSV files and there, in order to test, I have taken exactly the same CSV file so the same data as the first for which it works, but for the second I get one error, even though the query is exactly the same as before.

Here is the error in question :

**`Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2124;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid operand for operator: <assignment> [Invalid DATE] Target Data Type: <Date> Source Data Type: <Character> Target Name: DATE -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 81  AdsCommand query execution failed.`**

There is my query to insert data into the DBF file :

```
insert into ACT values('1','VENTE2','','20201084','','','400000','VEOSIS','','','04/15/2020','04/15/2020','04/15/2020','','',0,11,0,'',0,'',0,0,'',0,0,'',NULL,0,0,0,1,0,'',0,'','','')
```

There are four dates in this query, the three which are showy and the NULL.

Here is my function which starts the insertion of data in the dbf file :

```
    //Convert Csv to dbf file
    public void DataSetIntoDBF(string fileName, DataSet dataSet, string path, List<string> data) {
        try {
            if (File.Exists(path + fileName + ".dbf"))
                File.Delete(path + fileName + ".dbf");
            
            AdsConnection con = new AdsConnection(GetConnection(path));
            AdsCommand cmd = new AdsCommand();

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            File.Copy(@"C:\Users\Laura\Desktop\Projets\JDA_EMAIL\CONNECTOR\JDANEW\Email\PARFILUX\TemplateACTDBF\" + fileName +".dbf", path + @"\" + fileName + ".dbf");              

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string dat in data) {
                string insertSql = "insert into " + fileName + " values(";
                string[] values = dat.Split(";");
                foreach (string val in values) {
                    if (fileName == "ACT")
                        insertSql += GetCreateTableACT(dataSet, false, val, i);

                    i++;
                }

                insertSql = insertSql.Substring(0, insertSql.Length - 1) + ")";
                cmd.CommandText = insertSql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                i = 0;
            }
        
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I use the Advantage Data Provider library to insert my data (https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=19&Product=4&Platform=11).

```
    private string GetConnection(string path) {
        return "data Source=" + path + ";User ID=;Password=;ServerType=local;ReadOnly=true;pooling=true;TrimTrailingSpaces=true;TableType=CDX;LockMode=COMPATIBLE";
    }
```

Here is the code that formats my data :

```
    private string GetCreateTableACT(DataSet dataSet, bool creation, string value, int i2) {
        string createSql = "create table ACT (";

        int i = 1;
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dataSet.Tables[0].Columns) {
            string fieldName = dc.ColumnName;
            string query = null;
            string type = dc.DataType.ToString();
            if (i2 == 10 || i2 == 11 || i2 == 12 || i2 == 27) {
                if (creation) {
                    createSql = createSql + "[" + fieldName + "]" + " date,";
                } else {
                   return query = "" + (value==""?"NULL" : "'" + value + "'") + ",";
                }
            } else if(i2 == 15 || i2 == 16 || i2 == 17 || i2 == 19 || i2 == 21 || i2 == 22 || i2 == 24 || i2 == 25) {
                if (creation) {
                    createSql = createSql + "[" + fieldName + "]" + " DECIMAL(17,3),";
                } else {
                    return query = "" + value + ",";
                }
            } else if ((i2 >= 28 && i2 <= 32) || i2 == 34) {
                if (creation) {
                    createSql = createSql + "[" + fieldName + "]" + " logical,";
                } else {
                    if (value.ToUpper() == "TRUE") return query = "1,";
                    if (value.ToUpper() == "FALSE")  return query = "0,";
                }
            } else {
                if (creation) {
                    createSql = createSql + "[" + fieldName + "]" + " varchar(50),";
                } else {
                    return query = "'" + value + "',";
                }
            }

            if (creation)
                i2 += i;

            //if (i2 == 28 && creation)
            //    break;
        }

        createSql = createSql.Substring(0, createSql.Length - 1) + ")";
        return createSql;
    }
```

If you have an idea I am interested :D
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried passing the dates in ISO format? 2020-08-17 for example?  I expect the real fix is to use SQL Parameters and parameterize your query, but that might get you working.

Comment: I totally agree with what you say but why does it work for the first one knowing that the second will be the same ? : /
Unfortunately, for the dates I have to keep them in this format at all costs.
Thank you for your reply !

Comment: it probably works for the first one, as the day is less than 12.  If you query back the DB, you've probably swapped the day/month.

Comment: This is impossible because the query is exactly the same so the dates too.
Thank you for your reply !

Comment: @LauraDestier I wouldn't dismiss Mike suggestion so easily. While I do not know the Advantage SQL Engine, the error message is pretty much clear that there is a problem with dates. YYYY-MM-DD is ANSI SQL then I would give it a try (it seems that the engine is configurable, BTW). Also _"...keep them in this format at all costs"_ doesn't make sense. How you receive/store/visualize them has nothing to do with the format you use when sending them to - in this case - the SQL engine. MUCH BETTER: drop this _build SQL code by hand_ entirely and use the proper approach (parameters).